# How to call PostgreSQL function from C code (ECPG)?

Tags: c, postgresql, ecpg

We are porting Oracle Pro*C code to PostgreSQL ECPG. We had several Oracle stored procedures that were ported into PostgreSQL functions like:

```
db1.update_some_logic(double precision, double precision, text, text)
```

On the C file I've tried several things but nothing seems to work.

Option 1:

```
EXEC SQL SELECT db1.update_some_logic(10411, 920, 'TYT','N');
```

Error 1:

```
too few arguments on line 4379
```

Option 2:

```
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
const char *stmt2 = "SELECT db1.update_some_logic(10411, 920, 'TYT','N');";
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;
EXEC SQL EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :stmt2;
```

Error 2:

```
too few arguments on line 4384
```

The function clearly has 4 arguments, not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Is `update_some_logic` a function or a procedure ? If this a function, what is the return type ?

Comment: @pifor it's a PG function (we ported Oracle stored procedures to functions), return type void

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue with PostgreSQL 12.3.

I have found following workaround:

- the function should not return void but a value for example an integer
- the ECPG program must execute the function and get the returned value with  `SELECT ... INTO`:

`EXEC SQL SELECT update_some_logic(10411, 920, 'TYT','N') INTO :v_key;`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need work with share variables for those parameters.

```
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;

double parameter_1;
double parameter_2; 
char parameter_3[100];
char parameter_4[100];
int result; //I guess your function return int??

EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;


EXEC SQL SELECT update_some_logic(:parameter_1, :parameter_2, :parameter_3, :parameter_4) INTO :result;

if (sqlca.sqlcode!=0)
{
  printf("Error: %ld\n", sqlca.sqlcode);
  printf("Message:%s\n", sqlca.sqlerrm.sqlerrmc);
}

printf("It works %d\n", result);
```